# Reportar error de escritura en un texto

Tags: bug, soporte, estado-completado

Cuando marco una respuesta como acertada y pongo el mouse encima de la marca, me sale un texto indicando que si quiero cancelar la marca debo volver a hacer clic. Dicho texto está mal o incompleto como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, añado otro detalle al bug: cuando se habla de respuesta acertada, creo que la palabra correcta es "acertada", y no como dice en casi todos lados: "aceptada".

Creo que la respuesta no se "acepta", si no que se "acierta".

Comment: Solo para agregar más detalles sobre el bug, sucede cuando la respuesta se acepta el mismo día en que se hizo la pregunta.

Comment: No consigo reproducir este problema, ¿sigue ocurriendo?

Comment: Es difícil porque para comprobarlo ahora tendría que marcar una respuesta como acertada y en este momento no tengo.

Comment: @AdrianaHernández sobre la traducción de la palabra "accepted," seguiremos usando la traducción "aceptada" porque esta da la mejor explicación de lo intentado en inglés.  La palabra "acertada" da por entender algo más preciso, cosa que es subjetivo al juzgar. Te pido que intentes reproducir este bug de nuevo y avisarle a **Konamiman** en cuanto puedas. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Tú haces una pregunta, el otro usuario la responde y tú _aceptas_ su respuesta como la mejor de todas; no veo dónde encajaría aquí la palabra "acertar". Si acaso, quien ha acertado es el otro usuario con su respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo tu interpretación pero yo me refiero a que el otro usuario acierta con su respuesta y quien hizo la pregunta la marca como respuesta acertada. Esa es mi interpretación. Pero bien, creo que se puede interpretar de las dos formas. Saludos. :-p

Answer (score 1):

Ahora sobra la palabra "**el**" (al menos para el siguiente caso en el que la aceptación fue hace 20 segundos).

Aparece de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cierto, ese "el" sobraba. Quitado, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la traducción de aceptada, esta bien, ya que es el usuario quien dice que esa respuesta es la que el acepta como válida, aunque siempre queda sujeto a la interpretación de los usuarios